# Customize shadows with cardslib

Tags: android, cardslib

I'd like to change default shadow for material card with Cardslib.

I have card

```
<it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardViewNative
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/list_cardId"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="@style/native_recyclerview_card.base"
card:card_layout_resourceID="@layout/native_material_largeimage_card"/>
```

According to documentation https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/SHADOW.md#customizing-shadow I added card_shadow.xml with my values to /drawable folder and it's doesn't make any sense.

What's wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Custom shadow works with `CardView` and you are creating `CardViewNative`

Read at the start of the page https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/SHADOW.md

> **Pay attention**: the CardViewNative doesn't use this view, because it is
>   natively supported.
>
> All the features below are supported only by CardView